# SQL - % Breakout by Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a query that will break out what percentage of time is utilized within a hour given a time range.

Sample data:

```
    declare @date table(id int, Start_time time, End_time time)
    Insert Into @date(id, Start_time, End_time) values
        (0, '09:15', '17:15')
        , (1, '10:45', '16:30')
        , (2, '08:05', '17:45')
        , (3, '07:00', '15:00') 
        , (4, '07:30', '8:30')
```

Looking to get output like this:

[image: expected output]

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I can't read the result.  Perhaps they could be included as a *text table* in the question.

Comment: What attempts have you made? This doesn't seem particularly difficult; just the number of minutes used in the hour divided by 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using an ad-hoc tally table to create every minute of the day.  This assumes you are processing to the minute.  Then it becomes a small matter of the conditional aggregation.

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select A.ID
            ,Hrs = datepart(hour,T)
            ,Cnt = convert(decimal(10,2),sum(1.0) / 60)
        From @date A
        Join (
            Select Top (1440) T=dateadd(MINUTE,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),0) From master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
            ) B on T >=convert(datetime,Start_Time) and t<convert(datetime,End_Time)
        Group By A.ID,datepart(hour,T)
)
Select ID
      ,h3  = sum(case when Hrs=3  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h4  = sum(case when Hrs=4  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h5  = sum(case when Hrs=5  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h6  = sum(case when Hrs=6  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h7  = sum(case when Hrs=7  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h8  = sum(case when Hrs=8  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h9  = sum(case when Hrs=9  then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h10 = sum(case when Hrs=10 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h11 = sum(case when Hrs=11 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h12 = sum(case when Hrs=12 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h13 = sum(case when Hrs=13 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h14 = sum(case when Hrs=14 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h15 = sum(case when Hrs=15 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h16 = sum(case when Hrs=16 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h17 = sum(case when Hrs=17 then Cnt else 0 end)
      ,h18 = sum(case when Hrs=18 then Cnt else 0 end)
 From  cte
 Group By ID
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go

Comment: @markyice Made a small correction ... removed the between.  you may notice H17 is 0.25 now and not .27

Comment: @markyice To be clear.  This does span days.  For example 11PM to 7AM (night shift)

Comment: Can you also explain From master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 if you dont mind

Comment: @markyice It is just a table that is known to exist.  We use that to create an ad-hoc tally table 0,1,2,3,...1440 via the row_number() function.  ANY table of appropriate number of rows can be used.

Comment: roger! Thankyou!